# How to set priority in Microsoft Luis Patterns?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am using pattern recognition to catch entities with a variable size. Here are situation that i am trying to catch

```
1- {entity1} (has| had| have) [the] {entity2}

2.1- {entity1} (has| had| have) the {entity2}

2.2-  {entity1} (has| had| have) {entity2}
```

i tried the 1 pattern or the 2.1 and 2.2 at the same time.
The problem is that when i enter: "Person have the properties"

the entity2 is marked as "the properties" instead of just "properties"
Is there a way to mark priority or work around this problem?

Sorry for english mistakes i hope that the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way you can set priority in LUIS patterns. However, given your situation above, where the entity is getting extracted incorrectly, you might want to make use of [explicit lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/reference-pattern-syntax#explicit-lists). You can create an explicit list via the [authoring API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/reference-pattern-syntax#explicit-lists) to allow the exceptions when:

- Your pattern contains a Pattern.any
- When that pattern syntax allows for the possibility of an incorrect entity extraction based on the utterance.

Also, make sure to refer to the best practices(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices#do-and-dont) for LUIS apps to make sure your app behaves with improved accuracy.

Hope this helps.